# OneNote 2016 : Choose highlight colour not available to a tag

Tags: microsoft-onenote, office365, microsoft-office-2016

I'd like to go ahead and change the tag highlight colour on OneNote, to something much more easier/softer on the eyes and the text I'm trying to read.

The highlighting for general text in OneNote offer a suitable and easy on the eyes green that I want to use instead of this harsh green. However, the colour options for the tags themselves are much more limited and don't have any more transparent colours (save for a light grey, but I don't fancy putting light grey all over my notes). I'm fairly good with technology, and wouldn't mind it if there were some back-end files I needed to go through to make this change.

I'm using OneNote 2016 from Office 365.

Image of what I'd like:

[image: Image of what I'd like]

Comment: I can't say for certain for OneNote 2016, but I use 2013 and I know MS have deliberately limited your options to customise styles and presentation. I've tried to do exactly this myself and been frustrated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **Onetastic** for OneNote https://omeratay.com/

Onetastic is a free multi-purpose addin for Microsoft OneNote. You can **program** in OneNote without using the raw XML.  There are many utility programs ready to use including several for highlighting (called shading in Word.)

---

Greg Maxey, a Word MVP, has a **highlight tool addin** for Word that does exactly what you request. http://gregmaxey.mvps.org/word_tip_pages/highlighter.html.

"The add-in will hopefully offer a solution to the problem of odd and often too dark highlighter colors available with the standard Word highlighter tool."

---

A Great page to show *lighter versions of colors* (and the HEX code for them) is http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_colorgroups.asp .  Look at the bottom of the page under **White Colors**.  Also look at the previous and next links at the top of the page for some other nice color adjustment techniques

---

You can use **VBA** in Word to ***Program OneNote*** but OneTastic is much easier. If you seriously want to make "backend changes," here are some other suggestions. Be warned that the OneNote VBA programming documentation is meager compared to programming Word or Excel.

You can programmatically "shade" in Word using the Shading object on a selection or a range. You want the change the **background color**. The syntax is *myRange.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor =  wdColorTurquoise*.

The "Shade Object" is different from the "highlight object" in Word so Highlight searches in the Find/Replace dialog will fail.

A place to start programming the OneNote Object Model is https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj680118.aspx

As an alternative, you could programatically highlight your material in Word, and copy your selection to OneNote since the background pattern color is preserved when you copy and paste. You then have the organizing/grouping powers of OneNote with the Technical wizardry of Word.